# Default modules in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I wanted to check the modules loaded by default in Python, I ran the following code:

```
import sys

for key in sorted(sys.modules.keys()):
    print(key)
```

I got a long list which included modules like os, math etc. So, does that mean these modules need not be imported explicitly ? My point is why these modules and not others? For example, I see the lzma module. Why this module?

Comment: So you've decided to ask instead of try to use any of listed module without import and see what happens?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Please see edit

Answer (score -1):

When you run your code, you get something like this:

```
abc
argparse
array
ast
asyncio
asyncio.base_events
asyncio.base_futures
asyncio.base_subprocess
asyncio.base_tasks
asyncio.constants
asyncio.coroutines
asyncio.events
asyncio.exceptions
asyncio.format_helpers
asyncio.futures
asyncio.locks
asyncio.log
asyncio.protocols
asyncio.queues
asyncio.runners
asyncio.selector_events
asyncio.sslproto
asyncio.staggered
asyncio.streams
asyncio.subprocess
asyncio.tasks
asyncio.transports
asyncio.trsock
asyncio.unix_events
atexit
backcall
backcall.backcall
base64
bdb
binascii
bisect
boto3
...
```

And so on(The output may differ).

It means these libraries are already available on your machine. You need not to explicitly install it but you have to import it in your code every time. Like:

```
import os
```

Else you get an `ModuleNotFoundError`, and to install any library, you need to use `pip`.

Comment: "It means these libraries are already available on your machine" - that is not what that output means. It's a list of modules that *some code somewhere* has already imported in this Python process. Many more modules may be available.

Comment: (As an aside, if you actually ran the code and the output actually looked like that, your environment is kind of weird. Most environments wouldn't have all those modules already loaded.)